# myqsldump thowing an error code (1054)

Tags: mysql

Can you please advise me what I am doing wrong here? My sqldump command is not working correctly as it ?

```
mysqldump -u jim -p mydb mytable --where mycondition="ERROR-5000-JAVA" > /home/jim/issue1.sql 
Enter password: 
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mytable` WHERE mycondition=ERROR-5000': Unknown column 'ERROR' in 'where clause' (1054)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need quotes around the whole `--where` option, so that the double quotes around the value will be sent to MySQL.

```
mysqldump -u jim -p mydb mytable --where 'mycondition="ERROR-5000-JAVA"' > /home/jim/issue1.sql
```

Comment: Thanks mate ! works like a charm. I always get confused in mysql when to put "double quotes and when to put ' quotes. Any idea ? This time around I used " after = sign as I got an idea from another thread but didn't work as I had to use ' after --where. Its all confusing ....

Comment: You have to remember that the shell also processes quotes. So if you want MySQL to see the quotes, you have to escape them or wrap them in more quotes.

Comment: About your MySQL quote confusion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks